# How to add linebreaks in map pushpin content?

Tags: windows-phone-7, dictionary, bing, pushpin

I've just started using maps in my Windows Phone application and I can't figure out how can I have linebreaks in the pushpin's content. Here's my code:

```
<my:Map Height="756" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="map1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="468" CredentialsProvider="Auc_zPo5mypWlRwCBm73jnZE0D-6AqBQq6bSdt8XpRA" Center="41.6154423246811, 0.738656005859375" ZoomBarVisibility="Visible" ZoomLevel="12" >
        <my:Pushpin Location="41.6154423246811, 0.738656005859375" Content="First line, \n second line" />
    </my:Map>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a template for the content of your pushpin:

```
<my:Pushpin>
    <StackPanel>
        .. your content here
    </StackPanel/>
</my:Pushpin>
```

Note that default property of Pushpin (i.e. a ContentControl) is it's "Content" so you can directly edit it's content by adding codes between tags.

Here is a good source of information about customizing pushpins:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg266447

Comment: Thank you for the link, it might be useful sometime!

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Environment.NewLine`

eg

`Mypushpin.Content = "This is line one "+ System.Environment.NewLine + "and this is line two!";`